# How to capture and replace string of numbers after certain text with Logstash's grok?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

We have a message with the following structure in a log where we want to hide the `accountId` information using Logstash's grok:

> Message: Timestamp: 19-02-2015 13:55:37
>   CorrelationId: xx999-9999-99999-9999-xxxxxxxx
>   Data: RequestMessageId - sdgersc-345frh-346yfh-34563sd-345634d
>   Data: ReplyMessageId - 1123223-xx235-xx234-x46sdg-654segsdg
>   Data: -100 - NameOfTheService_020: Error message
>   Data: accountId - 1324235234
>   Data: caseNumber - 123235345

We want to filter out the `accountId` information and preferably replace it with the text "hidden".

We cannot find a way to replace data in grok, so we tried to use grok in the filter as follows:

```
grok { 
    drop_if_match => "message", "Data: accountId - ${NUMBER}" ]
}
```

This returns that the expression does not return a boolean.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not that difficult,

```
gsub => ["message", "Data: accountId - \d+", "Data: accountId - hidden"]
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to replace things in grok. You need to  use `overwrite` in the filter.  http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok

E.g.

```
grok { 
    overwrite => "message"
    match [ "message", "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" ]
}
```

Typically that's for chopping off stuff like timestamps, and keeping the message text. But I don't see why you couldn't use that to clobber account ids.